# A $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$-module $M$ is torsion free iff $\text{soc}(M)$ is torsion-free

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, socle

Let $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$. I'm reading a proof that a $\mathfrak{g}$-module is torsion-free iff its socle is torsion-free.

One direction is clear, but for the other, if $M$ has torsion, then one gets that $M$ has a nonzero weight vector $v$. They say that the submodule generated by this weight vector intersects the socle nontrivially, so the socle is not torsion-free.

Why does the weight submodule have to intersect the socle nontrivially? That's the part I don't understand.

Comment: Iirc, since $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple, by Artin-Wedderburn so is every $\mathfrak{g}$-module, and thus $M = \operatorname{soc}(M)$.

Comment: @GuidoA. Thanks, that works if $M$ is finite dimensional, but infinite dimensional reps of semi-simple Lie algebras need not be semi-simple I think.

Comment: You're right, my bad

Comment: Any non-trivial submodule has non-trivial intersection with the socle (this is essentially what the socle is).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I think my edit shows the socle is an essential submodule in this case, but is it clear a priori? I thought the socle is not always necessarily an essential submodule.

Comment: As long as you know that your module has at least one simple submodule, then the socle is essential. I need to think a bit on why this is the case here (if we assume that the module is finitely generated that should be enough, as the enveloping algebra is noetherian). You can't argue by just dimension, since the simples need not be finite dimensional.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Oh right, my mistake.

Comment: Ahh, so after thinking a bit about it, I read the argument again. The idea is that the submodule generated by the weight vector will be a highest weight module, and we already know that these possess at least one simple submodule (being quotients of Verma modules).